Shimano Ultegra 9500 set rear mech skips 8th gear
I'm riding a stock Schwinn fastback road bike from around 2004 that came with a Shimano Ultegra 9500 set, with 2x9 speeds. I have never messed with the derailleurs as they've always worked fine. The bike has not been ridden enough to have problems from wear. After not riding it much over the last 15 years, I took it up from the cellar and noticed that while all other shifts are smooth and accurate, it skips past 8th gear to 9th in both large and small front cogs. Never noticed this before. Adjusting both the downtube cable stop and the barrel adjuster on the rear mech, I can get it to shift up into 8th but then it won't go to 9th gear. I would hate to do this but I could release the cable (open up rear mech cable screw) and screw the barrel adjuster all the way in, then back out a turn or two, and start from scratch to set up the shifting, but I don't know where the "start" position would be for the downtube cable stop (the kind with a lever/wing on it for the rear mech, indexed with 4 positions, with the wing pulled back toward the top tube, placing rear mech farthest from the wheel hub, and then being pushed down towards the front wheel 4 clicks, moving rear mech towards wheel hub). Any ideas where the downtube cable stop should be set to begin a set-up? Or, any other ideas for how to fix this?
